# What does the [worksheet-function] tag mean?

Tags: support, tags

What does the [worksheet-function](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) tag mean?

> This tag is for spreadsheet questions where the question or answers involve an in-the-cell worksheet function, as opposed to some form of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worksheet functions are usually like the following that you can type directly into the cell:

```
=SUM(A4:Letter)
```

or

```
=YEARFRAC(DateOne, DateThree, Basis)
```

These are built-in to the cell functionality. This is opposed to if you have to write a script or macro to do some other calculation or such like.

The tag description is henceforth and shall be asking for answers where you do not have to write a macro, but instead are looking to use an in-built cell formula for the results.

Comment: When we ask a question, we would usually tag it with `google-spreadsheet` or `MSExcel`. Then, shouldn't no-scripts be the default behavior? I mean shouldn't the question be tagged as `scripts` if you want script and if you don't tag it as such it's taken for granted that you are looking for a `worksheet` solution?

Comment: Maybe you're asking about how to better use a worksheet-function, something that you want to limit to that, instead of allowing for workarounds with scripts

Comment: But tagging it with [tag:google-spreadsheet] or [tag:microsoft-excel] already implies that worksheet-functions are included. So what's the point of adding the [tag:worksheet-function] tag? Should we propose that it be removed?

Comment: Not all the time. Some times you want specifically on the worksheet function. Other times you want to talk about general use of the web app